# Maven 3 - Exclude child JAR from WAR

Tags: maven, jar, war

Disclaimer: I've looked at a lot of similar question on SO and the web, but I can't seem to find any that apply to my specific circumstances.

I'm trying to implement Maven 3.0.5 in an (very large) old project that currently uses Ant. As a first step, I'm simply trying to build an artifact with the same structure as currently done with Ant build scripts.

This requires that I build an EAR containing several JARs and several WARs. So far, so good. I can do that bit.

The problem is that each WAR receives every dependency in the project, and all the child JARs of these dependencies. This is bloating each WAR to ridiculous sizes.

What I need to do is the WAR equivalent of

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>*</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

I've seen it suggested to use

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

but that results in the exclusion of the initial dependency itself, which I need.

Is there a way to include JARs but to exclude *their* dependencies from a WAR file?

Comment: I'm not sure how classloading works with EAR files, but if that does work, you could try this: add a maven profile to each of the war projects, and this profile will build an artifact with a classifier, and it would exclude a lot of dependencies.  Then in the pom for the EAR, have it depend on the artifact with the appropriate classifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provided is what you want to use here.

However, you will need to make sure that at least *some* component actually includes the jar files necessary for your application. As long as when the application runs, it has all the necessary jars in the classpath, it will run fine. It will build/compile using the parent dependencies, but the scope argument will prevent them from being included in the sub package's target directory with the assumption that it will be in the classpath at runtime as part of the parent or another package. It's up to you to ensure that "provided" is indeed the case.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as it seems the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

The JARs you include depend on their dependencies for a reason!   You can't just cut the dependency tree, you'll break your libraries and probably your code.

If you want, you can unpack all of the JAR files into a single directory, do a manual build, and do some coverage testing so you know exactly what classes you will and will not need.  Then, you can re-package (manually) the classes into a new JAR file tailored for your application.

I don't recommend doing that at all, though.  You may still break stuff, and disk space is cheap.

Comment: I know it sounds ridiculous, but that's the situation already. I'm adding Maven support to a project that has previously had manually managed dependencies, thus the dep tree has never been in place.

Comment: Oh, I may have misunderstood the situation.  If you're saying that your project's dependencies are not already tracked in Maven (ie you are migrating the project to Maven), then Maven will not help you clean up any croft / unused dependencies that have accumulated in there - you'll have to do the hard work of slowly replacing the provided dependencies with Maven managed code.

But the "solution" you are looking for (filtering on GAV id) makes it sound like the project's dependencies are already Maven artifacts...  so I'm confused.

Comment: @BadZen, yes disk space is cheap, but java classes get loaded onto the perm gen space, meaning it consumes precious ram.

Comment: If the Java classes are not needed/used, they won't be loaded.   If they are loaded in the course of running the application, you're going to get a probably fatal runtime exception if you delete them from the project and try to run it!

Comment: actually I have deleted jars while an app was running and it kept going fine, I think it just fails if it tries using a class that is not currently in perm gen.  Yes it won't load classes it doesn't need, but if it concludes that War A and War B both depend on a class /foo/Bar, and each has it's own identical copy of that, I'm worried it might load the same thing twice.  Still, it's not a huge deal since classes typically consume a very small amount of memory when compared to the heap space.

Comment: @msknapp If you're worried it will load the same class twice because two different classes have a dependency to it, please review how Java class loading works.   The only way that goes down is if there are two different ClassLoader explicitly loading it twice, and you can believe it that happens in the context of a web application, it needs to happen.

Anyway, Will is trying to remove them from the project, not delete them out from under a live webserver.   For all that is good and holy, why would you torture your poor webserver like that???  ;)

Comment: I never said we want to delete them from a live webserver, I was merely trying to prove that classes are loaded into RAM.  You can have fewer versions of the same class on the classpath if the web server lib provides the artifact, instead of having one copy of it in every war.

Comment: Getting the discussion warning.   TLDR here is if Maven says you need it, you need it.  Even if there are multiple versions of the same class in there.  You need them all.

Comment: @BadZen I'm in the process of migrating to Maven, so I've moved as many as possible into Maven, but some of them are so old (Jakarta, anyone?!) that that isn't possible. Sorry for the confusion.